# Build exe and webapp using msbuild commandline

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-devops

I am trying to build a solution using ms-build command line, which contains multiple projects.

Four of them are creating an exe file as output and rest are creating a single web application.

Now when I try to build them together using msbuild, it throws out error-

```
/p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true  /p:outdir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Error -

```
error MSB4057: The target "ResolveWebJobFiles" does not exist in the 
project.
```

Note - If I remove property "/p:WebPublishMethod=Package" then it runs well but doesn't create the zip file.

Can anyone please suggest me any property by which I can create the zip file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Webjob-List.json file that can be found in properties.

I was using an old reference for the project that was missing from there, deleting the path solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone please suggest me any property by which I can create the zip file?

Are you deployed the web application as Azure WebJobs with the Azure Website? If yes, you should make sure the you have installed the below package in your web project. The package id="`Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish`" version="1.0.2".

If not, I am not very sure the reason why you got this error "*The target "ResolveWebJobFiles" does not exist in the 
project*" before I can access your web project. But I would like provide a workaround to you, you can check if it works for you:

Edit the `*.csproj` file, add zip target in your project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Link Include="bin\*.dll" />
    <Link Include="bin\*.exe" />
    <Link Include="bin\*.exe.config" />
</ItemGroup>

<Import Project="..\.build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
<PropertyGroup>
<ReleasePath>bin</ReleasePath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Zip Files="@(Content);@(Link)" WorkingDirectory="$(ReleasePath)" ZipFileName="output\$(AssemblyName).zip" ZipLevel="9" />
</Target>
```

Note: You need add the nuget package "`MSBuildTasks`" and you can change the `ReleasePath` to other folder.

See [this document](https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2013/06/14/how-to-create-deployment-zip-packages-for-any-microsoft-visual-studio-2012-project-type-simply-by-editing-the-csproj-files/) for more detail info.

Comment: Thank you leo, Thanks for waiting for that long time after posting answer. Though I got the solution the path reference in Properties/WebJob-List.json was not proper because of which it was throwing that error

Comment: Thanks For your reply

Comment: @Mukul, np. How about this issue now if you correct the path reference in Properties/WebJob-List.json?